# Webpack different loaders for different js entries

Tags: webpack

Can you load an secondary entry with a different set of loaders?

For instance, I'm trying to create a service worker for offline caching. I've excluded the folder that contains the service worker and included it on the other. There are no calls to the service-worker.js (it's just manually loaded in the static index.html). The service-worker entry point is picking up React and hot loader instead of just going through Babel. Here's the salient parts of my config.

```
entry: {
     app: "app.js",
     'service-worker': 'persistence/service-worker.js'
},
module: {
    loaders:[{
        test: /\.js|\.jsx/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "jsx?harmony", "babel"],
        exclude: /persistence/
    }, {
        test: /service\-worker\.js/,
        loaders: ["babel"],
        include: /persistence/
  }]
```

Comment: I don't see why something like this couldn't work. Are you having some particular problems with the setup?

Comment: the service-worker entry builds with all the javsscript packages and doesn't include only the 1 file in the persistence folder.

Comment: Maybe the safest bet is to define a separate configuration for your service worker. That would seem like the cleanest solution to me.

Comment: I encounter the same situation, your solution work ! just check if the entry and loader match perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I settled on using the file loader (with babel-loader to preprocess the js files). It works in hot-loader as well as my production Docker/Node environment.

```
loaders: {
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: [/src/,/bower_components/],
    exclude: [/persistence/],
    loader: 'jsx?harmony!babel'
  }, {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [/persistence/],
    loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]!babel'
  }, 
  ...
},
```

This config excludes the folder from the normal JS files and separately copies over the Service Worker files into the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use inline loader syntax in entry points to make this work (tested in Webpack 4.42.1)

The following `webpack.config.js` will apply `raw-loader` to `script.js` for the `script_raw` entry point but not for the `script_plain` entry point.

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
      'script_raw': 'raw-loader!./script.js',
      'script_plain': './script.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: '/app/out',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

this would get unwieldy pretty fast for your situation but could be a building block to do other interesting things.